# Homeomorphism between $(-\infty, a)$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I want to find a **homeomorphism** between $(-\infty, a)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. The only function I could find that sends every element in $\mathbb{R}$ to $(-\infty, a)$ is
$$f(r)=a-\vert r\vert$$
However this isn't even injective so it's far from being an homeomorphism. Can someone help me here?

Comment: what about exponential functions?

Comment: @RyanK could you go a bit deeper?

Comment: what sets does $e^x$ map between?

Comment: @RyanK do you mean defining $f(r) = a-e^r$ for example?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, now you just have to check if its actually a homeomorphism.

Comment: Consider $\ln(a-x)$.